# Is it possible to apply a VS2019 suggestion for an entire document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to enact a Visual Studio suggestion (such as 'Fix Naming Violation') for an entire document or project? EDIT 2: I would like to do so for all class property names, which are all different in spelling.

When creating c# models for a json model that is known, you can use Paste Special to get the basic layout. However, since json is commonly camel case, the property names get pasted in the same way. The 'Fix Naming Violation' suggestion shows for each property, but I cannot seem to find a way to do so more globally.

I know you can change the naming violation rules, but was still curious to know if this is possible so as to follow C# convention.

I would post a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation.

EDIT 1:
From:

```cs
public string classProperty1 { get; set; }
public string classProperty2 { get; set; }
public string classProperty3 { get; set; }
```

To

```cs
public string ClassProperty1 { get; set; }
public string ClassProperty2 { get; set; }
public string ClassProperty3 { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. You can definitely automate intellisense actions but you're gonna have to roll your own. I know right when you change the name of a property, you get a brief chance to accept visual studio's suggestion to refactor your propagate the name change. If you change a name, you can immediately hit Ctrl-. (period) to see intellisense suggestions for refactoring. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/rename?view=vs-2019

Comment: Some of the code fixes have, in the preview window, also an option to apply this to the whole document or even project

Comment: @ZakkDiaz yes when I hit Ctrl + . there is an option to 'Fix Naming Violation' (to capitalise the class property name), but only for that property. Refactoring options only work for everything with the same name. What I want to do is to capitalise all property names of the same document which all have different names. This is because when i go to Edit -> Past Special -> Paste as JSON classes for a large JSON object, sometimes there are more than a hundred property names. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I tried preview changes just now but there doesn't seem to be an option to target the whole document for 'Fix Naming Violation' unfortunately :(

Answer (score -1):

### Step 1:

Just hover over and locate the suggestion or just hit `Ctrl + .` on where you want suggestions.

For eg:

[image]

### Step 2:

Under the `Preview Changes` section, choose the scope of the suggested fix.

You get *Document*, *Project* and *Solution*.

For example, I want to apply this suggestion to the whole *Solution*.

[image]

Make selections if you'd like.

### Step 3:

Click `Apply`.

Comment: On IDE1006 (naming rule violation) as mentioned by @Jeffrey Huang these options are not visible, so this solution does not work.